# NodeJS Photoshop PSD parser toJSON() has no method

Tags: json, node.js, psd

Im using https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js to parse a PSD file in node,

I see that toJSON() can be used, https://github.com/won21kr/psd.js-1

but when I try to use on a simple hello world after installing the module,

> npm install psd

toJSON() gives me error:

> info = psd.toJSON();
>              ^ TypeError: Object # has no method 'toJSON'

normal log works fine,

```
var PSD = require('psd');
var psd = PSD.fromFile("AntoineVeglas_Filter_BW.psd");
psd.parse();

node = psd.tree().descendants()[0];
console.log(node);

info = psd.toJSON();
```

how to parse to valid json my psd tree object? cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are aware that `toJSON` function is in a fork project of the original right? So if you install `psd` using `npm`, you will get the original project which has no `toJSON` function.

You should checkout the fork (`won21kr`) and either put it in your `node_modules` folder, or put it somewhere else and access the `js` file with a relative module path notation: `require('./psd-fork/index.js')`.

Answer (score 0):

change psd.tree().descendants()[0]; to psd.tree().descendants()[0].export();